# Using media queries in html

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I wrote a simple `HTML` program for experimental purposes:
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: green;
}

@media screen and (device-height: 375px) and (device-width: 667px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Media queries are simple filters that can be applied to CSS styles. They make it easy to change styles based on the characteristics of the device rendering the content, including the display type, width, height, orientation and even resolution.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

But ut doesn't change color when it is tried in iPhone 6. What is wrong with the code? Is logical expression correct?

Comment: `device-width` and `device-height` will calculate exact width and height. So use `min-height` and `min-width` instead of `device-width` and `device-height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me on the iphone 6:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 374px) and (max-device-width: 376px)
```

this works on the iphone 6+:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 413px) and (max-device-width: 415px)
```

Comment: So I should use `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`?  Check first answer

Comment: Great,this worked... But how do you know the values?

Comment: trial and error^^ pls accept the answer if it works:-)

Comment: Accepted the answer  :)

Answer (score 1):

This works in a browser and hopefully on your IPhone too:

(Max-width and min-width instead of device-height and device-width)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: green;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 375px) and (max-width: 667px) {
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Media queries are simple filters that can be applied to CSS styles. They make it easy to change styles based on the characteristics of the device rendering the content, including the display type, width, height, orientation and even resolution.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use max-device-width and min-device-height.

```
@media all and (min-device-width: XXXpx) and (max-device-width: XXXpx)
```